# Cannot load url in WebView

Tags: android

I've set my minimum API at `API 17: Android 4.2` and I'm attempting to load `https://www.google.com` in a `WebView`. I'm testing on the default Nexus 5X API29 x86 virtual device in Android Studio. I rarely dabble with Android so all of this is new to me but it appears that I have a permissions issue.

When I load the url, the WebView displays the following text: `Webpage not available The webpage at htps://www.google.com/ could not be loaded because: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I am instantiating the WebView from my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mytestprojects.projectname">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my activity_main.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="138dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="363dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried with any other URL? It seems it is your network issue, check your proxy/ firewall settings as well.

Comment: Try emulator without google play, had same issue not so long ago... WebEngine was crashing and you can not do anything about it except use other avd version with same API

Comment: Having the same problem with the virtual device. It works fine though with when run on real device.